# Gulp Sass is not compiling CSS file

Tags: html, css, gulp

I just started a new project but can't get my gulp sass up and running as its not compiling. I've used the same code for other projects but its now started to fail on me.

**Below is my gulp.js file**

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var bourbon     = require("node-bourbon").includePaths;
var neat        = require("node-neat").includePaths;
var cleanCSS    = require('gulp-clean-css');

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
    server: "./app"
});

gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
               .pipe(sass({
                   includePaths: bourbon,
                   includePaths: neat
               }))
               .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
               .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


// Minify main.css file
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
      return gulp.src('app/css/main.css')
                 .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('minified-css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Also what strategies should I use to debug this issue.

Comment: This exact gulpfile has worked for you before? Either your `package.json` allowed an updated version of some dependency to introduce a breaking change, or you have a breaking error in one of your source files

Answer (score 0):

```
.pipe(sass(your options).on("error", sass.logError))
```

I note that you are watching and gulp.src'ing in two different ways:

```
gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass']);

return gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
```

What happens if you change the .src() to the same as the .watch??